# @BindingAdapter not working with Android Kotlin library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I've this [`BindingAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) to load image using `Glide` in my **library** module

```
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide

@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
    Glide.with(view)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .into(view)
}
```

and I tried to use the adapter like this

```
   <ImageView
            ...
            app:imageUrl="@{`http://pngimg.com/uploads/alfa_romeo/alfa_romeo_PNG75.png`}"
            ... />
```

but am getting

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:imageUrl' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.ImageView.

The weird thing is, when I convert the `BindingAdapter` to `Java` from `Kotlin`, it works.

```
public class ImageViewBindingAdapter {

    @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    public static void setImageUrl(ImageView view, String url) {
        Glide.with(view)
                .load(url)
                .into(view);
    }
}
```

NOTE: This issue only exist with the `library` module. App module works perfectly fine with the `Kotlin` file.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you added dependency `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"` inside library gradle?

Comment: Try adding `@JvmStatic` above `@BindingAdapter`.

Answer (score 10):

Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52668004/1607169

TL;DR:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
```

instead of

```
@BindingAdapter("app:imageUrl")
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this

```
object BindUtil {
  @JvmStatic
  @BindingAdapter("app:imageUrl")
  fun imageUrl(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
      Glide.with(view)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .into(view)
  }
}
```